# Reading a file and adding an extra "\"

Tags: java, string, file-io, split, special-characters

I am reading some data from a text file. Some of the data could have a "\" in fornt which i want to keep. The issue i am having is that when i store this data in a string var java adds another "\" in front which i guess is because "\" is a special character in String. Is it possible to store the data without Java adding an extra "\"

```
String line;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
 {
 String[] arrLineElements = line.split(":");
 if(arrLineElements.length<=1)
  logWriter.write("Error in line:"+line+". Need at least 2 elements. Skipping line.");
 if(arrLineElements.length==2)
 {
  Dn dn = new Dn(arrLineElements[0], "", false, arrLineElements[1], "", false, "", false);
  dnList.add(dn);
 }
}
```

The data in the text file is in the following format:

> \+441506441111:\+441506442222
>
> 3333:4444

After I run the java code the data is stored in the dn object as

> \\+441506441111:\\+441506442222
>
> 3333:4444

Anyway to change that?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you see this in a debugger or something?

Comment: @PeterTillemans Yes i am using eclipse and in debug mode i am seen it in the var.

Comment: Indeed, the backslash you see is not really there. It is a way to show that "\\n" means really \n and not Carriage Return.  Eclipse just shows the string as you would see it in source code. Easy for copy-pasting.

Comment: @PeterTillemans thanks got it ... just the way the debug displayed the value "\". I ended up writing the var to file to confirm but i got it. Thanks. Not sure how to make comment the right answer? Thanks again

Comment: your welcome, I just told the same as Waqas, only differently. I would give his answer the sign of approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java adds another "\" in front which i guess is because "\" is a
>   special character in String

It is an escape sequence yes.

I do not get why would you need to change that inside the String itself? You can use this string. 
i.e. use it in

```
System.out.println("\\+441506441111:\\+441506442222");
```

and it will print with single .

You just need to use this String wherever you want

Comment: Hi @Waqas ,Thanks for the feedback but maybe i am not explaining it well. I am storing it in String lets say "String foo". So in the debugger i am seen var "foo" as \\+441506441111. When i use foo to say construct an SQL statement it then uses \\+44 ... instead of \+44...

Comment: In debugger, it might show this.. but when u pass it to the query, and then print the query to console System.out.println(query), you will not get double \\ but single.

Answer (score 0):

1. When reading from file, java need to escape the '\' special
   character.
2. When creating a String in order to represent that same text:

   - in a code point of view, the extra '\' is there;
   - in a output perspective you will see only one '\'
3. The conclusion is:

   - you will read one '\'
   - in the debugger or other way to see the code, you see "\"
   - but if you print the text back, will be only one '\'